# VB.NET and MS Access - Binding (Data won't save to database)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, binding

I have linked one of my VB.net forms to an MS Access database table, However, when I save the data entered from the VB form into the data set, the data will show in the data set but it will not appear in my database table. Is there anyway I can get the data that I have stored in the data set to appear in the actual database.

I have bound the form fields correctly to the database table and I have added the tables to the form via a data grid.
![Form & Data grid][1]

Can anyone tell me why it won't save to my database? or does anyone have an alternative method for binding forms to a database.

*Note - My database also has a password on it (don't know if that effects it)

*Note - I'm new to this forum so i cant post an image...

*Note - Let me know if you need to see more code

**Form loading code**

Public Class CD_FORM

```
Private Sub CD_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CDKingsDatabaseDataSet.CD' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.CDTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CDKingsDatabaseDataSet.CD)

End Sub
```

**ADD Button code**

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles add.Click
    CDBindingSource.AddNew()

End Sub
```

**SAVE Button code**

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles sav.Click
    CDBindingSource.EndEdit()
    CDTableAdapter.Update(CDKingsDatabaseDataSet.CD)


End Sub
```

Comment: The reason new users can't post images is to discourage them from trying to post screen shots of their problem. We can't search or copy code from screen shots. Screen shots don't show enough of the code or error messages, and show too much extraneous information. Instead, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30609768/edit) your question to include as much code as will [show us the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited my question and provided some additional coding. Let me know if you require more code or if you have a solution. Thanks

Comment: I'll bet that your data actually is saved and you're just not looking for it properly, which is very common.  When you call `Update`, it will return a number.  What is that number?  If it's not zero then your data is being saved and we can go into why you're not seeing it.

Comment: I don't see a number. When I click 'save' the data saves directly into the data set but then disappears when I close the application and reopen it. Where would I see this number?

Answer (score 0):

Ah Ok I've found the solution thanks to a comment by jmcilhinney on the "VB.NET - .accdb database not saving changes" question made a while back. 
The changes to my database have been made but the database I was looking at was in the wrong location.

The database which stored the changes was in my bin/Debug folder.